# Media query in style.css doesn't affect all header parts. How can I target all headers?

Tags: css, wordpress, header, media-queries

This is my code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

header {
    background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

On mobile, my main header (Header Dark Small > Group > Row) stays the default background color while a different header (Header Dark Small > Spacer) does change blue.

html:

```
<div class="wp-site-blocks">
  <header class="wp-block-template-part">
    <div class="wp-container-8 wp-elements-7 wp-block-group alignfull has-foreground-color has-background-background-color has-text-color has-background has-link-color"         style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px">
      <div class="wp-container-6 wp-block-group alignfull" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:0px">...</div>
      <header class="alignwide wp-block-template-part"></header>
    </div>
    <div class="wp-block-spacer" style="height:66px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>
</header>
```

Changing the code on chrome, I found something I don't understand:

```
.wp-site-blocks > * {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

That doesn't affect main header. But when I move up and change:

```
.wp-site-blocks, body > .is-root-container, .edit-post-visual-editor__post-title-wrapper, .wp-block-group.alignfull, .wp-block-group.has-background, .wp-block-cover.alignfull, .is-root-container .wp-block[data-align="full"] > .wp-block-group, .is-root-container .wp-block[data-align="full"] > .wp-block-cover {
  padding-left: var(--wp--custom--spacing--outer);
  padding-right: var(--wp--custom--spacing--outer);
  background-color: red;
}
```

That does change the main header's background color.

Comment: Can you share the snippet of html that contains the working and not working version

Comment: Sorry. How do you do that?

Comment: just copy and past the html in your question.  Also, have you tried doing background-color: blue !important;

Comment: Tried !important but it didn't work. Edited post to include html (I think that's the relevant part?)

Comment: I created a fiddle of your project and it seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/exg9pdst/ this tells me its probably another style that is overriding it.  Try looking at my answer for examples

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you html looks like i can only hazard a guess.  But it looks like maybe you are using a third party to style things such as bootstrap.  Have you tried

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

header {
    background-color: blue !important;
    }
}
```

or specifying a more strict selector such as

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

div.wp-site-blocks header.wp-block-template-part {
    background-color: blue !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try styling by specifying the classes you have in each header.

e.g.

```
 header .wp-block-template-part {}
```

If it doesn't work try to use !important in your CSS properties because as I see they are wordpress classes

Answer (score 0):

I used Google Chrome's inspect element to find, copy, and paste the relevant style.css code, and that solved my issue.